# Ruby - HTTPS get calls with headers

Tags: ruby, https, header

Have a query on making a https Get call with headers. I tried the following

```
uri = URI.parse("https:\\www.someurl.com")

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)

# Following is where I am adding the header
req['Auth'] = "Bearer" + @token
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host,uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  http.request request
end

puts(response.body)
```

I see the following error

```
400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

I tried searching and what I have found is that `Net::HTTP.get` supports https calls but without headers.

The call that I am making is via API gateway, so I will have to add a token in the header.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `URI.parse("https:\\www.someurl.com")` should give you a `URI::InvalidURIError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `use_ssl: true`.

```
uri = URI('https://secure.example.com/some_path?query=string')

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  request['Authentication'] = "Bearer %s" % @token
  http.request(request) 
end
```